# Utilizing the LDT (Local Descriptor Table)

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to do some experiments using different segments besides the default code and data user and kernel segments. I hope to achieve this through use of the local descriptor table and the modify_ldt system call. Through the system call I have created a new entry in LDT which is a segment descriptor with a base address of a global variable I want to "isolate" and a limit of 4 bytes.

I try to load the data segment register with the segment selector of my custom LDT entry through inline assembly in a C program, but when I try to access the variable I receive a segmentation fault.

My suspicion is that there is an issue with the offset of my global variable, and when the address is calculated, it exceeds the limit of my custom segment therefore causing a seg fault.

Does anyone know of a work around to this situation?

Oh, by the way, this is on an x86 architecture in Linux. This is my first time asking a question like this on a forum, so if there is any other information that could prove to be useful, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I realized that I probably should include the source code :)

```
struct user_desc* table_entry_ptr = NULL;

/* Allocates memory for a user_desc struct */
table_entry_ptr = (struct user_desc*)malloc(sizeof(struct user_desc));

/* Fills the user_desc struct which represents the segment for mx */
table_entry_ptr->entry_number = 0;
table_entry_ptr->base_addr = ((unsigned long)&mx);
table_entry_ptr->limit = 0x4;
table_entry_ptr->seg_32bit = 0x1;
table_entry_ptr->contents = 0x0;
table_entry_ptr->read_exec_only = 0x0;
table_entry_ptr->limit_in_pages = 0x0;
table_entry_ptr->seg_not_present = 0x0;
table_entry_ptr->useable = 0x1;

/* Writes a user_desc struct to the ldt */
num_bytes = syscall( __NR_modify_ldt,
                   LDT_WRITE, // 1
                   table_entry_ptr,
                   sizeof(struct user_desc)
                   );

asm("pushl %eax");
asm("movl $0x7, %eax"); /* 0111: 0-Index 1-Using the LDT table 11-RPL of 3 */
asm("movl %eax, %ds");
asm("popl %eax");

mx = 0x407CAFE;
```

The seg fault occurs at that last instruction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can only guess, since I don't have the assembly available to me.

I'm guessing that the line at which you get a segfault is compiled to something like:

```
mov ds:[offset mx], 0x407cafe
```

Where `offset mx` is the offset to `mx` in the program's data segment (if it's a static variable) or in the stack (if it's an automatic variable).  Either way, this offset is calculated at compile time, and that's what will be used regardless of what `DS` points to.

Now what you've done here is create a new segment whose base is at the address of `mx` and whose limit is either `0x4` or `0x4fff` (depending on the `G-bit` which you didn't specify).

If the `G-bit` is 0, then the limit is `0x4`, and since it's highly unlikely that `mx` is located between addresses `0x0` and `0x4` of the original `DS`, when you access the offset to `mx` inside the new segment you're crossing the limit.

If the `G-bit` is 1, then the limit is `0x4fff`.  Now you'll get a segfault only if the original `mx` was located above `0x4fff`.

Considering that the new segment's base is at `mx`, you can access `mx` by doing:

```
mov ds:[0], 0x407cafe
```

I don't know how I'd go about writing that in C, though.

Comment: This is right.  The address of `mx` *relative to the new `DS`* is now `0`.  Rather than loading your new segment descriptor into `DS`, you should load it into `ES` and use segment overrides to access it (loading `DS` will affect *all* data accesses in your C code).

Comment: This is what I get when I disassemble the ELF with objdump:

8048a48:       c7 05 8c 9e 04 08 fe    movl   $0x3424cafe,0x8049e8c
8048a4f:       ca 24 34

This is fairly new subject material for me so I'm not sure which of the bytes are the ones used for the segment register override modifier. Also, is the address shown in the assembly code an offset into the default data segment? If that's the case do I need to alter the address of where the variable is initialized to?

Comment: This is the breakdown:  `c7` is the opcode for `MOV r/m32, imm32`. `05` is the MOD/RM byte, which says that the memory operand is addressed only by displacement.  The displacement is in the following four bytes: `0x08049e8c`.  The next four bytes are the immediate `0x3424cafe`.  This means that the offset of `mx` inside the default data segment is `0x08049e8c`, and that's the offset inside the new `DS` that you're accessing.