# Where is modify_ldt?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-calls

I am looking for the [`modify_ldt`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/modify_ldt) function (or constant for `syscall`) on ubuntu, but I can't find it's declaration anywhere. It's not in `sys/types.h` (as the man page suggests), nor in `linux/ldt.h` (doesn't exist) or `linux/unistd.h` as says [here](http://linux-documentation.com/en/man/man2/modify_ldt.html).

Where is it located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `__NR_modify_ldt` for the syscall constant.  On my system it's defined in `asm/unistd_64.h`, which is included from `unistd.h`

Comment: Thanks. btw any idea to which descriptor field `user_desc::content` (2 bits) corresponds?

Comment: No idea, sorry.  Might want to post another question.

Answer (score 0):

As Karl already said, call system call directly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771136/utilizing-the-ldt-local-descriptor-table)